# Unix Shell .bash_profile script open two files in sublime text in same window

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sublimetext3

So I have the following code in my .bash_profile file. This code allows me to use the `sub` command followed by the folder/filename to open that folder/file in sublime text! Thats awesome!

However I'm trying to open the .bash and .bash_profile files in sublime text using the `editbashpro` command as defined by the alias... however it opens BOTH files in SEPARATE windows.

I do NOT want to fix this issue by changing settings in Sublime Text itself, which it seems all of the tutorials out there are directing me towards this...

Is there any way to open both .bash and .bash_profile in the same window in sublime using only the terminal/bash_profile script? I'm **extremely** new to the terminal and using shell scripting? idk what its even called? see how new i am?

```
# Sublime Text Open File/Folder Command
function sub() {
    open $1 -a "Sublime Text"
}
echo 'sub <file/folder> ->
    open file/folder in sublime
'

# Edit Bash Profiles Command
alias editbashpro='cd ~/;
sub .bash_profile;
sub .bashrc;'
echo 'editbashpro ->
opens .bashrc and .bash_profile in Sublime Text Editor'
```

Comment: Is [Sublime Text 3 - OS X Command Line](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html) helpful?

Comment: Yea that doesn't help. Their code to create the symlink is out dated past OS X El Capitan. I can't get their commands symlinked correctly or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried passing both files to `open` at the same time instead of calling it twice? I'm not sure if it will help or not if you're resistant to turning off the setting that tells Sublime not to open all files in their own window, though.